# Update Javascript array, so I can pass it to PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I mainly write HTML and PHP, I am really not good with Javascript or Jquery.  But I also know Jquery and javascript have some really cool features that render on the computer or device which you are viewing the website site on.

I want the ability to select multiple rows with html input type='checkbox' and each one I click on, to automatically update a javascript or jquery array which will automatically update the  tag only on the computer.  This way when I click I the Link, then the page will change and PHP will take over.  This will be great if I don't have to use a form.

Below is an Example

```
<input type='checkbox' value='65' />
<input type='checkbox' value='66' />    
<input type='checkbox' value='67' />
<input type='checkbox' value='68' />

<a href='./?p=test&array=65,66,67,68'>
```

Result I am looking to get is array[65, 66, 67, 68]

I couldn't find a thread that answered this already, please excuse me if there was one already.  I may also not be asking it properly.

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wpan2j88/) will help

Comment: it is a lowercase L

Comment: check update [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wpan2j88/1/)

Comment: Why is it that you don't want to use a form? This is a perfect use-case for a form.

Answer (score 0):

Your html should be

```
<input type='checkbox' onclick ="getVal(this)" value='65' />
<input type='checkbox' onclick ="getVal(this)" value='66' />    
<input type='checkbox' onclick ="getVal(this)" value='67' />
<input type='checkbox' onclick ="getVal(this)" value='68' />
```

Your js will be

```
var list = [];
function getVal(cb){    
    list.push(cb.value);
    console.log(list)
}
```

Output will be ["65", "66", "67", "68"]

To remove the value if added in the array

```
var list = [];
function getVal(cb){ 
    if(cb.checked){
        list.push(parseInt(cb.value));
    } else{
       for(var i=0; i<list.length;i++ ) {
           if(cb.value == list[i]){
               list.splice(i,1);
           }
       }
    }    
    console.log(list)
}
```

Comment: what happens if the user clicks twice on the checkbox?

Comment: I would like: if the user click twice, then first to add to array, second click to remove from array, which checkbox will be de-checked.  This is great, however don't know how to add the array to the hyperlink.

Comment: the html remains the same, i have edited my above post pls refer

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is an eventListener which will help you to capture an event performed by user with your checkbox.

There are two event methods by which you can achieve this.

- onchange
- onclick

Whenever a user clicks the checkbox, these methods will get called. There is though a subtle difference between these two, but to start with any of them should work fine for you.

What you need to do is add one of these to your DOM. Like:

```
<input type='checkbox' value='65' onclick = 'doThisOnCLick(this)'/>
```

After this, you need to have this function defined somewhere in your relevant JS files. If you do not have any function yet, you can start by defining this on your HTML page itself within `<script>` tags.

```
<script>
   var someArray = [];
   function doThisOnChange(c){
     someArray.push(a.value); //this will push 69 to array, similarly others can be pushed
   }
</script>
```

Hope this helps you. For better understanding, I suggest get a little taste of JS. Its simple and awesome

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){

var checked = $('input:checkbox').map(function() {
   return this.checked ? this.value :null ;
 });

console.log(checked);

});
```

This will log the checked items.

Look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q6on6j4s/1) for demo

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Add a class to the checkboxes so we can add a click event to them,
then at click event we take all the selected elements using the `:checked` selector we get the values from them using `val()` and we push them to array using `push()` after that we encode the array (that is converted to string by joining the elements in it) using `encodeURIComponent();`

The new string resulted is appended to the href attribute of the link using the `attr()` function

```
<input class="el" type='checkbox' value='65' />
<input class="el" type='checkbox' value='66' />    
<input class="el" type='checkbox' value='67' />
<input class="el" type='checkbox' value='68' />
<a class="link" href="">link</a>

var array_elements = [];
$('.el').click(function(){
  $('.el:checked').each(function(i,v){
  array_elements.push($(v).val());
  });
  var url = './?p=test&array'+encodeURIComponent(array_elements.join(','));
  $('.link').attr('href',url);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zgjeo8sw/2/

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. You create a `jQuery` script that updates your link whenever the check boxes are clicked like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='chkbx' value='65' />
<input type='checkbox' class='chkbx' value='66' />    
<input type='checkbox' class='chkbx' value='67' />
<input type='checkbox' class='chkbx' value='68' />

<a href='./?p=test&array='>

<script>
    $('input.chkbx').click(function(){
        value = $(this).attr('value');
        link = $('a').attr('href');
        // to get the last character of the link
        lastC = link.substr(link.length -1);
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
           if(lastC == "=") {
               $('a').attr('href', link+value);
           } else {
               $('a').attr('href', link+','+value);
           }
        } else {
            y = link.splice(',');
            y.splice( $.inArray(value, y), 1 );
            x = y.join(delimiter);
            $('a').attr('href', x);
        }
})
</script>
```

This way u will update the link to add the new value of the check box and also when the check box is unchecked, it removes its value from the link also

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, the output of `str` variable will be like `65,66,67,68` which can be used to build the query string

```
var str = '';
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
          str += $(this).val()+',';
    });
    str = str.replace(/,$/,'');
    console.log(str);
});
```